# What does the SL/off button on the Focus FC-286N TTL speedlight do?

Tags: hotshoe-flash, slave-flash

I have a focus FC-286N speedlight for Nikon.  What does the SL/off switch do on the back? I cannot find any reference to SL anywhere on the internet.

The last few times I have used this speedlight, it has gone berserk! It flashes when it wants to and just...crazy!  I turned this SL button to "off" and it seems to have settled down.  What does it stand for, and what does it do? And why can't I find out anything about this anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but it is probably for the "Slave function" listed in the [specs](https://www.focuscamera.com/focus-bounce-swivel-speedlite-dslr-flash-for-nikon.html).

When it is turned on, any sharp increase in brightness, such as another flash firing, detected at the optical sensor on the bottom front of the flash will trigger the flash. When in slave mode most shoe mounted flashes ignore the signals received through the contacts on the bottom of the foot of the flash.

> And why cannot find out anything about this anywhere?!!

I couldn't find a manual for the flash online. Did it not come with any printed instructions when you bought it?